# Finding all distinct graphs with n nodes(networkx)

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-neural-network

For example, I want to find all the graphlets with 4 nodes. It will give me 11 distinct graphs.[image: Like this]. Is there a function or easy way to generate all these graphs in networkx. I am new to networkx so I do not know all of its features.

I am expecting to get all the unique graphs of fixed size n.

Answer (score 2):

All the graph variations can be generated with `networkx` using `nx.graph_atlas()`, see the [docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.atlas.graph_atlas_g.html#networkx.generators.atlas.graph_atlas_g) and the official [plot example](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/auto_examples/graphviz_layout/plot_atlas.html).

By default, this function will generate all graphs that have up to (and including) 6 nodes, so to keep only the four-node graphs an additional condition is needed:

```py
from networkx import graph_atlas_g

four_node_graphs = [g for g in graph_atlas_g() if len(g.nodes())==4]
print(len(four_node_graphs))
# 11
```

Comment: I have limited knowledge on graph networks and have a project that needs me to use networkx, any suggestions on good tutorial/book I can use to get on top of things quickly?